# C++ Structure with unknown data types

Tags: c++, data-structures, type-conversion

My program reads user's input and create easy "table". User on the start specifies data types of columns and the number of rows.

User's input:

```
create table
add attribute string Name
add attribute int    Age
rows                   3
```

I need prepare a structure from user's input now. I have something like this:

```
CTable
{
    unsigned   attributesCnt;
    string   * attributesNames;

    void    ** attributes;
};
```

So, from the user's input, the progam does these steps:

```
CTable myTable;

myTable.attributesCnt = 2; // string "Name", int "Age"

myTable.attributesNames = new string[2];
myTable.attributesNames[0] = "Name";
myTable.attributesNames[1] = "Age";

attributes = new void[2]; // 2 attributes
attributes[0] = (void*) new string[3]; // there will be 3 rows
attributes[1] = (void*) new int[3];
```

I need remember that "attributes[0]" is string and "attributes[1]" is int too.

Is this "right" way?

I would like use only standard libraries.

Comment: You need something like [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: Ask yourself: What is the size of a void?

Comment: @uberwulu: Thanks for comment. I use a pointer to void, the size of pointer is based by platform. Is it true? Forward I don't know the number of attributes and their types. I need struct, where can I store "2 int, 3 string", or "1 int, 1 string", or "1 int, 2 char, 3 string, 1 double".

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Thanks. I looking for solution with use standard libraries.

Comment: Captain oblivious set you on the right track, you may also benefit from looking at [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: @Peter K., the reason I ask is because of this: `attributes = new void[2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a tagged union also called a variant. It allows you to store multiple data types at the same location just like a regular union but includes an additional but separate data member that indicates it's type. The C++ Standard Library does not include variants but they are easy enough to implement.

Once you have a variant you can apply it to your example like below.

```
myTable.attributesNames[0] = "Name";
myTable.attributesNames[1] = "Age";

// I recommend using std::vector here instead of using new/delete yourself
attributes = new Variant*[2]; // 2 attributes
attributes[0] = new Variant("player name");
attributes[1] = new Variant(player_age);
```

The following example shows how the variant might be implemented.

```
struct Variant
{
    enum Type
    {
        INT,
        STRINGPTR
    };

    Type    type_;
    union
    {
        int         int_;
        const char* stringptr_;
    }       data_;

    explicit Variant(int data) : type_(INT)
    {
        data_.int_ = data;
    }

    explicit Variant(const char *data) : type_(STRINGPTR)
    {
        data_.stringptr_ = data;
    }

    Type getType() const { return type_; }
    int getIntValue() const
    {
        if(type_ != INT)
            throw std::runtime_error("Variant is not an int");
        return data_.int_;
    }

    const char *getStringPtr() const
    {
        if(type_ != STRINGPTR)
            throw std::runtime_error("Variane is not a string");
        return data_.stringptr_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Variant intval(1);
    Variant stringval("hello");

    std::cout << intval.getIntValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << stringval.getStringPtr() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I still recommend you at least take a look at `boost::variant` and `boost::any`. They are a far more complete implementation.