# Constructing a array with various types

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

I'm writing a neural network class with [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) as my Linear Algebra back-end and I'd like to know how I create an array where each element has a different type, to be determined at runtime.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987521/how-bad-is-to-use-void-pointer-in-stdvector-declaration) but it didn't work for me.

All I want is to be able to access different-sized matrixes with an array-like access method, i.e. vMatrix[i].

Edit:

Prototype of the base class:

```
template<typename T, unsigned _Rows, unsigned _Cols> Eigen::Matrix;
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
vector< DerivedMatrix > vMatrix;
vMatrix.push_back(some_5x4_matrix);
vMatrix.push_back(some_4x10_matrix);
vMatrix.push_back(some_10x1_matrix);
```

The matrices sizes are not defined before-hand.

Since I know C more than C++ I think of a way to solve this: using struct with void* and some mechanism to store the items type or row & col; but I since I'm learning C++ I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Do the objects that you want to store in your array have a common base class? If yes you can use polymorphism.

Comment: I'm not sure Eigen supports non-numeric types.

Comment: You can use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` to accomplish this. If you can't use boost see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16770536/845568) answer for an example of  a basic variant implementation.

Comment: I do have a base class (Matrix), but it is polymorphic itself. I can't inherit a templated class unless its completely defined. Unions won't work here either because I would need to specify the types before-hand and I never saw any idiom that would allow me to do this. I'm updating the question to see I'm a little clearer.

Comment: have you seen this: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicStlContainers.html

Comment: Yes, I did @perreal, but they deal with fixed-size Matrices.

Comment: @luk51000, can you use matrixXd?

Comment: @perreal, I could, but it uses dynamically allocated arrays, which can't be processed at compile-time. I am looking for something that would allow me to completely define the neural network structure at compile-time, and even pre-compute some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a pre-determined, finite set of types you wish to support, you can use [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant).

You could also use [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/libs/any) as the element type of the array/vector.

Comment: The set of types is virtually infinite.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid to the most using boost since I'm trying to learn advanced C++. Any idea how they implement it?

Comment: Find it kind of ironic, judging by the fact that the most advanced C++ code I know of is in boost... But you can read the documentation. I'm guessing void pointers and RTTI (typeid). But that's only a guess. Like I said, boost is *very* advanced and has some nifty tricks up its sleeves.

Comment: I'm not saying it is not advanced, I'm saying I want to code the advanced stuff myself, so I can absorb it better. I was reading Boost.Any though and it seems it will do. I'll take a look at the source code. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following snippet? As far as dynamic sizes are concerned, you could resize the matrices at any point using the .resize() function. Does this help?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    vector<MatrixXf> A;
    MatrixXf P = MatrixXf::Random(2,3);
    MatrixXf Q = MatrixXf::Random(4,5);
    MatrixXf R = MatrixXf::Random(3,4);
    A.push_back(P);
    A.push_back(Q);
    A.push_back(R);
    cout<<A[0]<<endl<<A[1]<<endl<<A[2]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a runtime solution. I was looking for a compile-time solution. I saw a light with variadic templates, but couldn't dig much into that yet. I can post it here when i'm done if you want.

Comment: Yes please. Knowledge is a dish best served hot.